# Como usar AJAX dentro de un .PHP al momento de Importar datos de un .CSV

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
   <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="header.php"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Importando archivo CSV</h1>
    <form action='importar.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Importar Archivo : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' " value='submit'>
     </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

despues de crear el boton para importar los datos de un excel(.csv) tengo el php importar.php, en el cual es donde hago el llamado para cargar los valores

```
<?php

//conexiones, conexiones everywhere
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$mysql= new mysqli("localhost","root","","inci");

  if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
echo "no se pudo acceder a la base de datos";
  }
 else{
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //Aquí es donde seleccionamos nuestro csv
     $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
     echo 'Cargando nombre del archivo: '.$fname.' ';
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
     {
         //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
         $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
         $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
           //Insertamos los datos con los valores...

 $id=$data[0];
 $incidencia=$data[1];
 $resumen=$data[2];

  //tratar de usar ajax aca

  if ($resumen!="RESUMEN") {
 $query=$mysql->query("INSERT INTO registro(id,incidencia,resumen) VALUES ('$id','$incidencia','$resumen')");

         }
        }
         //cerramos la lectura del archivo "abrir archivo" con un "cerrar archivo"
         fclose($handle);
         echo "<br>Importación exitosa!";
         include 'nucleo.php';

     }
     else
     {
        //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive cuando es cvs, revisarlo para             //ver si esta separado por " , "
         echo "<br>Archivo invalido!";
     }   
}
}

?>
```

como se ve son 3 columnas que traigo de de mi pc, pero lo que pasa es que estos valores aparte cumpliran otra funcion...ya que no solamente los voy a guardar en un mysql, sino que mi mysql tiene 5 columnas y lo que pasa es que esos datos se van a interactuar,uno x uno... para que se vea mi interaccion cree el nucleo.php(que esta incluido en este codigo) en el cual realiza la funcion que deseo.

```
     <?php
     $mysqlx = new mysqli("localhost","root","","inci");   
     $cant0= $mysqlx->query("SELECT * FROM registro");
     $row_cant0=$cant0->num_rows;
     for ($w=1; $w<=$row_cant0 ; $w++) { 
     $mysqli0 = new mysqli("localhost","root","","inci");
     $rus=$mysqli0->query("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE id='$w'");
     while($h7 = $rus->fetch_object()){
       $incidencia=$h7->incidencia;
     $resumen=$h7->resumen;

     }


 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mantenimiento");
 $resumen2=strtoupper($resumen);
 $vres=0;
 while ( $vres<strlen($resumen2) && strpos($resumen2, ' ',$vres+1)!=null) {
   $x= strpos($resumen2, ' ',$vres);
   $y=$x+1;
   $z=strpos($resumen2, ' ',$y);
   $p=$z-$y;
   $vres=$z;
   $abc=substr($resumen2, $y, $p);
   //$cantidad=$mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT * FROM sites ");
   if (strlen($abc)>=6 && strlen($abc)<=7 && substr($resumen2, $y,2)=="AC" OR substr($resumen2, $y,2)=="LI"){
    if (strlen($abc)>6 && ctype_alpha($abc[2])) {
              $aa=substr($resumen2, $y,2);
              $ab=substr($resumen2, $y+3,4);
              $abc=$aa.$ab;
            }elseif (strlen($abc)>6) {
              $abc=substr($resumen2, $y, $p-1);
            }
            $cant= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM sites");
            $row_cant=$cant->num_rows;    
      for ($i=1; $i<$row_cant; $i++) { 
          $rs=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM sites WHERE id_site='$i'");
            while($f = $rs->fetch_object()){
              $scelda=$f->id_celda;
              $snom=$f->nombre;
            }
         if ($scelda==$abc) {
             $site=$scelda;
             $c=strpos($snom, '/',0);
             $d=substr($snom, $c+1,strlen($snom)-$c-1);
             $stab=$d;
             $vres=strlen($resumen2);
             break;
         }else{
           $site="";
           $stab="";
         }
       }
   } 
 }

   $mysqli8 = new mysqli("localhost","root","","inci");
    $fila2=$mysqli8->query("UPDATE registro SET sitio='$site' WHERE id='$w'");
      $fila3=$mysqli8->query("UPDATE registro SET nombre='$stab' WHERE id='$w'");


    }

   ?>
```

este proceso si se realiza de buena manera, el problema es el tiempo ya que demora en cargar, un minuto x 5 filas, y si tuviera un excel(.csv) de mas valores(10000) demoraria mucho mas, es por eso que mi cuestion seria si habria alguna manera de usar AJAX dentro de mi importar.php, para que cuando se cargue cada fila, se pasen los parametros y automaticamente se actualize en el mysql, ya que eso es lo que realiza el AJAX.

Comment: Es mala idea leer toda la base de datos solo para obtener el total de filas: "SELECT * FROM tabla"; en vez de eso usa la función COUNT: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla". Ahora, estaría bien que expliques lo que haces en el for, parece que lees todos los registros y solo obtienes los datos del último.

Comment: claro, con el for estoy buscando dentro de mi bd... con respecto a mi preguntaq si es que se puede usar AJAX en importar.php, es posible eso @Triby ?

Comment: lo que hago con el primer for es buscar el ultimo valor de mi Id, no es que quiero saber que cantidad de filas hay,

Comment: En ese caso puedes utilizar `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tabla`

Comment: pero con respecto a si es que se puede usar AJAX dentro de importar.php, es posible eso?

Comment: Por otro lado en el.primer bloque utilizas MySQL mientras en el segundo mysqli, mysql esta depreciada como tal, por otro lado podrías ayudarte con librerías como phpexcel o su predecesora para estos menesteres

Comment: Sí es posible usar AJAX, pero primero debes resolver el problema de consumo de recursos (y tiempo) para realmente avanzar. Por cierto, la sugerencia del COUNT(*) es para reemplazar el código donde lees $cant0->num_rows